# How many people live in Alexandria?

Tags: tv, the-walking-dead

On *The Walking Dead* - the television show, not the comics - do we know how many people were living in Alexandria Safe Zone, prior to the events of the second episode of season six, "*J.S.S.*"?

Again, I know that we have more information about Alexandria's population in the comics, but I am asking about the television show exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

At the peak of it's population, Alexandria *had* slightly over 53 residents, as listed on the [official wikia](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Alexandria_Safe-Zone_(TV_Series)) page. However, by my math there is a remaining (spoiler)

> 33 (give or take) residents after the events we have witnessed this season such as the attack by the Wolves and the break in by the walkers.

...

> Therefore, before the attack by the Wolves, the number should be around 51, seeing as though 2 residents (Pete and Reg) were killed before the Wolves and "The Herd" attack didn't occur until later in the season.

The uncertainty comes from the "Numerous other residents" bullet point on the Wikia page.

Answer (score 0):

no alexandria have over 98 residents still alive not 70 to 40 at least 100 something people are alive or unseen like mrs orson and mr orson luke john davidson but there is newcomers of alexandria thoe like maybe over 50 new comers in alexandria that makes 198 people now because the new comers like dwight laura siddiq and the workers who actually hates negan and some of the soldiers probably no lie or joke alexandria has more population now maybe more like unseen people or unknown alive but fighting others like saviors ore somthing. but i did seen katana died by enid and aaron by shooting her in the face so others from ocean side surrouned enid and aaron. so dwight is gonna go to the saviors base and get eugene back and dr carson and the workers over 980 of them or some savior soldiers who dont like negan as well and move to alexandria so learn to count.

Comment: This seems like it was intended as a reply for another user. You've also only got 1 full stop in about 8 lines of text. Consider [edit]ing your answer to make it clearer what you're trying to say.